# Can't bypass `Restricted` execution policy

Tags: powershell, batch-file, visual-studio-2015, executionpolicy

I a tool just downloaded that opens a Visual Studio Command prompt from within the IDE, in the root of the current project. My main gripe is that it opens an old style command window, where I would rather have a PowerShell window. According to [this post](http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/02/01/using-visual-studio-developer-command-prompt-with-powershell/), this simple change should allow this:

```
cmd.exe /k ""%VS120COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat" & powershell"
```

When I this command from outside of VS 2015, it seems to work fine and gives me a PowerShell window. Yet when I try and run it from inside VS, using the utility's menu item, it gives me this error:

> Cannot load PSReadline module.  Console is running without PSReadline.
>   . : File
>   C:\Users\brady\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
>   cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
>   For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:3
>   + . 'C:\Users\brady\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_pr
>   ...
>   +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess PS C:\Development\vNext\Commerce\src\Commerce.Test> Get-Execution-Policy
>   PS C:\Development\vNext\Commerce\src\Commerce.Test>
>   Get-ExecutionPolicy Restricted

My global execution policy is `RemoteSigned`, but in the same window that show me the error, when I run a `Get-ExecutionPolicy`, the returned value is `Restricted`.

I have tried modifying my command to include the PS switch:

```
cmd /k ""%VS140COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat" & powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass"
```

But this still gives me exactly the same error.

The output of the command suggested by @PetSerAl in the comments

```
[Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem;[Environment]::Is64BitProcess;Get-Executi‌​onPolicy -List
```

gives two different results. The first in a normal PS window external to VS:

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

And the second in the only PS window I can find inside VS, the Package Manager:

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process    RemoteSigned
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine       Undefined
```

Comment: Show output of this command: `[Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem;[Environment]::Is64BitProcess;Get-ExecutionPolicy -List`.

Comment: As an aside, you may want to look at using [StudioShell](https://studioshell.codeplex.com/) for your Powershell needs within Visual Studio.

Comment: @PetSerAl I'll check that out when get back to work on that project, but thank you very much for the tip on StudioShell. Installing as I type.

Comment: You could try `powershell -noprofile`.

Comment: @PetSerAl I have updated the OP with the results from your command.

Comment: You missing `[Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem;[Environment]::Is64BitProcess` part of my comment. It is essential because `LocalMachine` scope separate for 32-bit and 64-bit processes. And I wanted to see output of that command for windows where `Get-ExecutionPolicy` return `Restricted`, so to know from which scope that `Restricted` come.

Comment: @PetSerAl I don't know how you are reading, but I copied and pasted your command directly into my question. To me, it looks the same there, in your first comment, and the same as your comment here. IT does show all the execution policies, just none are 'restricted'.

Comment: @ProfK But where in your question two boolean values what returned by `[Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem;[Environment]::Is64BitProcess` part of my command? I see only results of `Get-Executi‌​onPolicy -List`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Oh, I see them, but I edited them out to post the list results. They are both `True` outside VS, and the 2nd one `False` in VS, as VS has always been and still is a 32bit process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure an external command and optionally configure a keystroke for it.

I just did this in my VS2015...neat!

**Create a cmd file**

Create cmd file to call `VsDevCmd.bat` (Developer Command Prompt for VS2015) and then PowerShell.

**dev14powershell.cmd**

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

**Configure External Tool**

Tools -> External Tools

[image: VS2015 External Tools]

Calls the cmd file above, starts in Solution Dir (configurable)

**Run the new External Tool**

[image: Run PowerShell External Tool]

**Result**

A new command window started in Solution Directory.

**Optional, configure keyboard shortcut**

Tools -> Options -> Keyboard

Search for `external` and remember the number/order of the command you created (4 in my case)

[image: Command shortcut key]

Hit assign and you have:

[image: Powershell Shortcut]

Comment: And we have a winner. Sorry, I must wait a while until I  can award your bounty.